# Problem of index while using remove() on a like array given by getElementsByClassName-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm encountring a problem of index while using remove() on a like array given by getElementsByClassName,
here is an example, after removing the 1st line , I click on plus button of the new 1st line but the value of 2nd line is updated instead,

[image]

Knowing that getElementbyClassName method return a live like array, it should work because everytime I remove a line, the like array update itself, **isn't it like that?**

here is how i wrote the code
*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>Input 1
    <button class="btn minus-button " type="button">-</button>
    <input type="text" class="quantity" value="0">
    <button class="btn plus-button" type="button">+</button> 
    <button class="rembtn">remove</button> <br>
</div>
    <div>Input 2
    <button class="btn minus-button " type="button">-</button>
    <input type="text" class="quantity" value="0">
    <button class="btn plus-button" type="button">+</button>
    <button class="rembtn">remove</button><br>
</div>
    <div>Input 3
    <button class="btn minus-button " type="button">-</button>
    <input type="text" class="quantity" value="0">
    <button class="btn plus-button" type="button">+</button> 
    <button class="rembtn">remove</button>
</div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and Javascript

```
var plusButton = document.getElementsByClassName('plus-button');
var minusButton = document.getElementsByClassName('minus-button');
var inputQty = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity');
var removeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('rembtn');

//adjusting the plus button; 
for (let i=0;i<plusButton.length;i++)
{
plusButton[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    let valueCount = inputQty[i].value;
    valueCount++;
    inputQty[i].value = valueCount;
   
})
  
}
//adjusting the minus button 
for (let i=0;i<minusButton.length;i++)
{
minusButton[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    let valueCount = inputQty[i].value;
    valueCount--;
    inputQty[i].value = valueCount;
    
})  
}
//adjusting remove button
for (let i=0;i<removeButton.length;i++)
{
    removeButton[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        removeButton[i].parentElement.remove();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> getElementbyClassName method return a live like array

Yes, but when you attach your listener to your buttons, you use an index `i` which doesn't update.

The buttons of the second line target the index `1` of the array (the second line) and when the first line disappear, they still target the index `1` of the array which is the third line you had before.

**EDIT**

**HTMLCollection**

The `getElementsByClassName` return an `HTMLCollection` which is some kind of an array updated when the DOM change. So If one element of the HTMLCollection is removed from the DOM, your HTMLCollection will contain one less element.

Example:

base : [elementA, elementB, elementC]

*Suppression of elementB*

new collection : [elementA, elementC]

**Array**

This was a special behaviour that we don't find in the classic `Array` class. Its value isn't updated unless you ask it yourself.

Same example:

base : [elementA, elementB, elementC]

*Suppression of elementB*

still the same array: [elementA, elementB, elementC] (but now if you try to use the elementB you will get an error cause it doesn't exist anymore).

Comment: So I have used the Array.from method inside my loop to convert the like arrays and it works ,
 does that mean that when I'm directly using the getElementsByClassName indide an eventListener the index of each element do not update itself, it should always be converted to an array ?

Comment: If you convert it into an array, the rows won't change. When you suppress the first line from the your page, it is not removed from the array (it will become null though) so the indexation will remain the same. That's why it works

Comment: by it is not removed from the **array** you mean the **like array given by getElementsByClassName**, so when suppress the first line from the page, it become null on the **array like**, therefore when I use the Array.from it gives me the array without the null case , is that it ? thanks in advance